# how many times should I throw the coin?

Tags: probability

How many times should I throw a coin such that the probability of getting a tail at least once is greater than 7/8?
If I throw a coin once, than the total number of cases is 2 and the favourable number of cases is 1. So you get 0.5
If I throw a coin twice, than the total number of cases is 4 and the favourable number of cases is 2. So you still get 0.5? What am I missing here?

Comment: In the second case, you have four possible outcomes: ${\color{red}(T,T)},{\color{red}(T,H)},{\color{red}(H,T)},(H,H)$. The *three* first ones are the favorable outcomes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of getting a tail at least once is equal to $1$ minus the probability of getting $0$ tails.  So we want to solve $1 - \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n > \dfrac{7}{8}$, which is true for $n > 3$, so $n=4$ is the first integer solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let us throw $n$ times. Our success is to have at least one tail. The complement is zero tails, its probability is $\frac{1}{2^n}$. So, we have the inequality $1-\frac{1}{2^n}>\frac{7}{8}$.